# OS.File.writeAtomic file location

Tags: firefox, npm, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have the following code to create a file from a Firefox Add-on SDK extension.

```
panel.port.on("mbData", function(data) {
    console.log("Recebi dados. Data: " + data);
    OS.File.writeAtomic("mb.txt", data, {write: true, create: true}).then(function(aResult) {
        console.log("Criei o ficheiro\n");
    }, function(ex) {
        console.log("Error!\n"+ex);
    });
});
```

The code above works great when I run using `jpm run`. But, when I create the xpi file (`jpm xpi`) and install it on Firefox it doesn't work. It seems that the file it's not being created. In addition, I can't access any log files.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. As it is, if anyone wants to test and try to help you they have to guess at what the rest of your code is in order to create something that can be run. While we desire to help you, by not having enough code available for us to duplicate the problem, you have made the amount of effort needed to even begin to help you quite high.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this line:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
```

Before to call the writeAthomic method.